# SAP DI API: How to add payments with multiple invoice?

Tags: c#, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I'm trying to post to SAP B1 from my add-on application payments with multiple invoices. I'm using C# in developing my add-on app.

Upon posting, SAP creates one payment for every invoice or payment detail but suppose to be the invoices of those payments belongs to one payment in my add-on app.

Here's my code.

```
    Payments _pay = (Payments)company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oIncomingPayments);
    Recordset _oRecordSet = (Recordset)company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
    _oRecordSet.DoQuery("select NextNumber from NNM1 where Series = 98");
    int docnum = int.Parse(_oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).Value.ToString());
    int errCode = 0;
    
    _pay.DocNum = docnum;
    _pay.DocDate = pay.DocDate;
    _pay.TaxDate = pay.TaxDate;
    _pay.DueDate = pay.DocDueDate;
    _pay.CashSum = pay.CashSum;
    _pay.CashAccount = pay.CashAcct;
    _pay.Invoices.SumApplied = pay.TotalPaid;
    _pay.Invoices.AppliedFC = pay.TotalPaid;
    _pay.Invoices.InvoiceType = BoRcptInvTypes.it_Invoice;
    
    foreach (var i in pay.Details)
    {                                       
       InvoiceHeader inv = new InvoiceHeader();
       inv = context.InvoiceHeaders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == i.TransactionDocumentNo);
       _pay.Invoices.DocEntry = Convert.ToInt32(inv.DocumentNumber);
                                            
       errCode = _pay.Add();
    
       if (errCode != 0)
       {
          string _errMsg = "";
          company.GetLastError(out errCode, out _errMsg);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am facing almost same issue, do you have any errors? What is your sap version? Also you said "those payments belongs to one payment". Can you give more explanation about this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to pay on account and do the internal reconciliation
https://answers.sap.com/questions/568503/internal-reconciliation-posting-using-sdk.html

https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2586911 (you need a S-ID for this link)